# more then 100 rows not inserting in postgresql using php throught form

Tags: php, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to insert more than 100 rows in to postgresql database using PHP in a loop. I am not getting any errors.

The data is getting inserted when i try to add around 50 to 60 records. but when records is around 100 and above it is not getting inserted.

Below is the code i tried. Please go through and help me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
     $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
       $array ='';
       $resultAgain ='';
    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

      // $sponsorship_id = $_POST['sponsorid'];
      $resultAgain=array();
      $resultAgain = $_SESSION['arr_rows']; 

   for ($i = 0; $i <count($resultAgain); ++$i) {

  $recieptid = $resultAgain[$i]['recieptid'];
  $childid = $resultAgain[$i]['childid'];
  $openingbalance_fee = $resultAgain[$i]['openingbalance_fee']; 
  $openingbalance_familyhelp = $resultAgain[$i]['openingbalance_familyhelp']; 
  $mayreciept = $resultAgain[$i]['mayreciept'];
  $december_reciept = $_POST['decreciept'.$resultAgain[$i]['presentclass']];
  $adminfees = $_POST['adminfees'.$resultAgain[$i]['presentclass']];
  $schoolfee = $_POST['schoolfee'.$resultAgain[$i]['presentclass']];
  $familyhelp = $resultAgain[$i]['family_help'];
  $year = $_POST['yearName']; 
  $submit = $_POST['save'];
        // call insert function 
          $sql1="SELECT fn_reciept_insert($childid,
                                        '$openingbalance_fee', 
                                        '$openingbalance_familyhelp', 
                                        '$mayreciept', 
                                        '$december_reciept', 
                                        '$adminfees',
                                        '$familyhelp',
                                        '$schoolfee',
                                        '$year',
                                         $userid,
                                         localtimestamp,
                                         $userid,
                                         localtimestamp)";
          $result1 = pg_query($dbconn,$sql1);
        if (!$result1) { 
    echo '<script>alertMX("Data Not Updated")</script>';
   }
else
   {
    echo '<script>alertMX("Data inserted Successfully")</script>';
   } }
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Show some code. How do You use PostgreSQL? PDO or pg_* ?

Comment: i am using postgreSQL pg_*.

Comment: Use `pg_last_error()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php to get some more details.

Comment: i used this pg_last_error() function but i didn't  get any errors.

Comment: Please see the code orderly

Comment: <?php
         $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
           $array ='';
           $resultAgain ='';
        if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
 
          $resultAgain=array();
          $resultAgain = $_SESSION['arr_rows']; 

       for ($i = 0; $i <count($resultAgain); ++$i) { 

      $recieptid = $resultAgain[$i]['recieptid'];
      $childid = $resultAgain[$i]['childid'];
      $openingbalance_fee = $resultAgain[$i]['openingbalance_fee'];

Comment: $openingbalance_familyhelp = $resultAgain[$i]['openingbalance_familyhelp']; 
      $mayreciept = $resultAgain[$i]['mayreciept'];
      $december_reciept = $_POST['decreciept'.$resultAgain[$i]['presentclass']];
      $adminfees = $_POST['adminfees'.$resultAgain[$i]['presentclass']];
      $schoolfee = $_POST['schoolfee'.$resultAgain[$i]['presentclass']];

      $familyhelp = $resultAgain[$i]['family_help'];
      $year = $_POST['yearName'];

Comment: if ($resultAgain[$i]['recieptid'] > 0) {

            // call update function 
              $sql1="SELECT fn_reciept_update($recieptid,
                                             $childid, 
                                            '$openingbalance_fee', 
                                            '$openingbalance_familyhelp', 
                                            '$mayreciept', 
                                            '$december_reciept',

Comment: '$adminfees',
                                            '$familyhelp',
                                            '$schoolfee',
                                            '$year',
                                             $userid,
                                             localtimestamp,
                                             $userid,
                                             localtimestamp)";
              $result1 = pg_query($dbconn,$sql1);

Comment: if (!$result1) { 
        echo '<script>alertMX("Data Not Updated")</script>';
       }
    else
       {
        echo '<script>alertMX("Data Updated Successfully")</script>';
       }
          }

Comment: else {
            // call insert function
  $sql ="SELECT fn_reciept_insert($childid, 
                                '$openingbalance_fee', 
                                '$openingbalance_familyhelp', 
                                '$mayreciept', 
                                '$december_reciept',
                                '$adminfees',
                                '$familyhelp',

Comment: '$schoolfee',
                                '$year',
                                 $userid,
                                 localtimestamp,
                                 $userid,
                                 localtimestamp)"; 
            $result = pg_query($dbconn,$sql);

Comment: if (!$result) {  
        echo '<script>alertMX("Data Not Saved")</script>';
       }
    else
       {
        echo '<script>alertMX("Data Saved Successfully")</script>';
       }       
          }
        }
  $submit = $_POST['save'];
}
?>

Comment: Please copy the code and check then only u can understand. I am inserting values in loop

Comment: First: It is very hard to read code from comments. You should edit Your question. Second: The listing looks very incomplete and there is a lot of code not relevant to Your problem, for example $_POST, $_SESSION and <script>. Try to write minimal example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Third: You call PostgreSQL function. It is little more complicated than plain SELECT. I would test if single query works without PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**First, make sure you are closing that db connection at the end of your script**. Then if you keep having problems, try increasing your `max_connections` https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server#max_connections

`ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections TO 300;`

and restart postgresql server.

Also the problem may not be in the amount of data you try to `INSERT`. You are creating the query using unescaped data. What that means? If one of your variables that you put into that big query string has a `'` character, the query string will get messed up and that is a big security problem (read about **sql injection**). Bigger the amount of data, bigger the chance a `'` will appear. You should [escape your data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php)